# How to find all .zip files and file size in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have `2TB` of data. I want to list entire `.zip` and `.rar` files and files size in the directory and I want to exclude `01_Personal` Folder directory.

I tried below command but it didn't work out.

```
find /home -type f ( -name ".zip" -o -name ".rar" ) ! -path "01_Personal Folder*" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 du -b | sort -n -r > winrar.txt
```

Any other way to find files and file sizes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"... it didn't work out"* - You should show the results. No one knows how it did not work.

Comment: You probably want to `-prune` when reaching the `01_Personal Folder`, rather than continuing to search there and throwing away the results.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below command.

```
ll `find -iname *.bz2`
```

Comment: I want file size also

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `find` has a predicate `printf` to create formatted output, including size. So you can combine the filtering and formatting together:

```
find /home -type f '(' -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.rar" ')' '!' -path "01_Personal Folder*" -printf '%P %k\n'
```

Note: remember to quote all tokens which might have special meaning. This includes the file patterns (*.zip, ...), parentheses, exclamation point which might mean somthing to the shell.

Filtering on the name/folder with find eliminate searching and size calculation on unrelated files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use find

find  -iname *.zip

Example: to search for all .zip files in current directory and all sub-directories try this:

find . -iname *.zip

This will list all files ending with .zip regarding of case. If you only want the ones with lower-case change -iname to -name

The command grep searches for stings in files, not for files. You can use it with find to list all your .zip files like this

find . |grep -e ".zip$"

After you get the list of .zip files you can easily find the size of them.

Comment: I tried this. But I need file size also. We have very huge data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command:
du -ah | grep -e ".zip" -e ".rar"

Explanation:
du shows the disk usage, -h is for human-readable size.
And grep will find the match for .zip and as for multiple words we'll use -e.

Comment: Tried but its taking all the files  different  files also its taking.

Comment: Okay just remove the " and try the below command:
    du -ah | grep -e *.zip -e *.rar
Give this a  try

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification to @prayas-pagade 's answer, I was able to achieve it using the following command:

`du -ah | grep -e "\.zip$" -e "\.rar$"`